# Jquery Selector - How to select next column textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, parent

Ok,

Here's the exampe:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <type="button" id="mybutton" value="insert">
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea>My Text</textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to change the textarea value when I click on my button. The value will come from a set variable. This code has no other IDs or classes to refer to. So I have the following

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function(){

  jQuery(this).parent().next()...????;

});
```

This will get me to the next column, but I don't know how to select the `textarea` from there.

I tried `child()`, another `next()` but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select child elements in jQuery we use `.children()`:

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).parent().next().children().val(some_variable);
});
```

Note that this will select all sibling elements to the `textarea` as well unless you add `textarea` as a selector in the `.children()` function call: `.children('textarea')`

You could also use `.closest()` and `.find()`:

```
jQuery('#mybutton').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).closest('tr').find('textarea').val(some_variable);
});
```

`.closest()` finds the first ancestor element that matches the selector, and find, well finds the selector in the descendant elements of the root-selection.

Some Documentation for ya:

- `.closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest
- `.find()`: http://api.jquery.com/find
- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children
- jQuery Selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ (I recommend checking this out as it's got some very useful selectors)

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried the same thing you said, but I had Child instead of Children.

Answer (score 1):

If this table might change in the future you don't want to be that ambiguous.  Here is something that is a little more concrete in what you want:

```
$(this).closest('table').find('textarea').val('your val');
```

**More info:**

[.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
[.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
jQuery(this).parent().next().find('textarea').val('CHANGE VALUE');;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways to achieve the same thing. The following is one

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('textarea').val("New Text");
```